# selected option in bootstrap dropdown list not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have attempted some possible solutions to get the selected item from the dropdown list in my bootstrap navigation bar but it doesn't seem to work. Help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Attached below is the screenshot of the dropdown

[image]

```
<li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" 
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         Language<span id="selected" class="caret"></span></a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">中文</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
 $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
  });
</script>
```

I have attempted this to add another function for my other dropdown list. When I click one of the dropdown, the other one changes also.

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" 
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span id="sort" class="caret">Sort</span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Date and Time</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Availability</a>
        </div>
      </li>



   <script>
 $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#sort').text($(this).text());

  });
</script>
```

Comment: what error can  you see in console? can you create a demo in snippet?

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @guradio When I select "English" from the dropdown, I want to display "English" in the navigation bar. 

Error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You are using jquery .Have you given the jquery reference in your codes?

Comment: it may mean that you have not included the jquery script in your code i tried in snippet your code work..

Comment: `$ is not defined` is clear that you have issue with jQuery referencing.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks! @guradio What if I have another dropdown list, do I need to add another jquery script again?

Comment: no it will work.. make sure you have unique ID to make it work though @SabrinaSaid

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
        $('#sort').text($(this).text());
    
  });


I have attempted this, when I click one of the dropdown, the other one changes also. @guradio

Comment: @SabrinaSaid update the OP.. So it is much better to see

Comment: just updated @guradio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use class to select the span.
2. Use `.closest()` to get the li
3. Use `.find()` to get the span

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').find('.caret').text($(this).text());


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Sort<span id="sort" class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Date and Time</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Availability</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         Language<span id="selected" class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">中文</a>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>
```